# Javascript Scope with Cross-File Private State - Public Private and Protected

Tags: javascript, oop, module, scope, closures

I want to implement a big javascript based application. I am trying to implement it in modules present across multiple files. The requirements are such that I need to implement it keeping the following things in mind:

1. There should be private properties of a Class which can be present across multiple files
2. Same goes with protected members. These should not be accessible from outside the closures defined.
3. I want to keep a scope for adding a custom script which can be included later (either using AJAX call and then using eval() on it or some other method. This script should be able to access the protected members but not private members.

Can someone help me with the basic design/architecture implementation for this?

Comment: You seem to have the basic design already thought out. What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: I am confused how to implement it. Coz if i create functions as part of Class , one of which would fetch and eval that script with local scope, I would like to restrict functions of that external script, not interfering with private variables. i.e. implementing in protected scope.

Also I am confused on how to keep the private state across multiple files